# How to bind like button in array list using ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an array list, In list, every item has a like button with the like count. Right now a system is like when I click on like button I got in return 1 mean liked but for changes display I am recalling API and refresh the page but I want to show changes without refresh page other social media app are working/doing. For this, I make one more value in return like count for ex. when the user clicks on like button it will return 1 mean like with the total count.

homePage.ts

```
toggleLikeState(UserId: number, PostId: number) {
this.storage.get('userID').then(async (loggedinUId) => {
  const value: UserLikedPost = {
    LoginUserId: loggedinUId,
    UserId: UserId,
    PostId: PostId
  };

  this.apiService.postLike(value).then(
    async (success) => {
      console.log("succ", success);
      this.IsLike = !this.IsLike;
      // this.feed.LikesCount = success.LikesCount; // Here is where you update your likes without refreshing. 
      this.apiService.getPostsfeeds().then((data: any[]) => {
        this.feedlist = data;
      });
    }, (error) => {
      console.log("Error", error);
    });
});
}
```

homepage.html

```
<div (click)="openfeedDetails(feed.PostId)" *ngFor="let feed of feedlist">
<ion-col tappable>
    <ion-icon class="liked" (click)="toggleLikeState(feed.UserId,feed.PostId);$event.stopPropagation();"
        tappable name="{{feed.IsLike ? 'heart' : 'heart-empty'}}">
    </ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span *ngIf="feed.LikesCount > 0">{{feed.LikesCount}}</span>
</ion-col>
</div>
```

please help...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I am not certain what you meant by you need to refresh the page to reflect the page likeCount & likeState.* 
However, **to optimize your code**, since in JS objects are accessed `by reference`, so if you modify likeState & likeCount for the clicked feed, it will automatically update in UI due to `angular bind`. You don't have to refetch the entire feed from the server unless you expect users to always see the latest state from the server.

```
    <ion-icon class="liked" (click)="toggleLikeState(feed);$event.stopPropagation();"
        tappable name="{{feed.IsLike ? 'heart' : 'heart-empty'}}">
    </ion-icon>

   toggleLikeStates(feed: Feed) {
    this.storage.get('userID').then(async (loggedinUId) => {
      const value: UserLikedPost = {
        LoginUserId: loggedinUId,
        UserId: UserId,
        PostId: PostId
      };

      this.apiService.postLike(value).then(
        async (success) => {
          console.log("success", success);
          feed.IsLike = !feed.IsLike;
          feed.IsLike ? feed.LikesCount++ : feed.LikesCount--;
        }, (error) => {
          console.log("Error", error);
        });
    });
    }
```

**NB: Please follow JS naming standard of pascal casing & camel casing for class & property names respectively**